# Appium + android + python how to get URL that I've just clicked?

Tags: python, android, selenium, url, appium

I have such environment Appium + android Simulator + python. I have to test such case:

1. I click on button in App
2. My app is going to website(in webView browser tester)
3. I need to check the URL

I can't use commonly used code:

> driver.current_url()

because it returns this error:

```
Method has not yet been implemented
```

I don't know how to get this URL. May be somebody has experience in that issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is failing probably because you did not switch the context:
while working with the app you are using `NATIVE_APP` context, but as soon as you opened the WebView you got at least once extra context

```
webview = driver.contexts[1]
driver.switch_to.context(webview)
url = self.driver.current_url()
```

This is a basic example, of course you need to check context name rather then put index=1 as in my example

You can find more examples [here](https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/91a9d6701430599637bb6895f9ffb078ee4bd052/test/functional/android/context_switching_tests.py#L24)

Comment: I'm very new to this and I'm sorry if my questions sound silly but I'm using  webView browser and I see that:
WebView, in Android, is the feature which allows any app to display a webpage as a part of its own activity, instead of opening it on a separate browser.
However, is there any new context?

Comment: context - is a term used within Appium tool to describe "layers" of the app. It has nothing to do with your Android app architecture.

Comment: When you are testing pure native app,  `driver.current_context` will return NATIVE_APP. When you test web application in browser on mobile device, the same call returns `WEBVIEW_<package name>`. Since native Android app and web app are different, some Appium APIs are context-specific and getting URL is one of them: works only for web app. But if you are operating in NATIVE context (clicking link that opens webview in app), you have to switch context before you start manipulating with a view

Comment: I can give you a good advice: read documentation to better understand the tool. Things will look way more simple :) http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/index.html